# Help me understand what the lady says in the video at 9:46

Tags: listening, comprehension

Could you please help me understand what the lady says in the below video at 9:46
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k95ln3wfTFs
Just one sentence that is not totally clear to me.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an [audio interpretation](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1857/53711) question with no context.

Comment: She says "Just one moment," indicating that the check-in process is almost but not entirely complete.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is of no value to future users and site visitors—or indeed to anyone other than the poster—and because the poster's question has been satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, "Just one moment."

Comment: "And just one moment."

Comment: Actually, I would argue that she doesn't say "and". She uses a speech disfluency that sounds like "nnnn...". In American English (I am unsure of other countries) this kind of sound of is something of a filler with a meaning something close to "please wait".